# How do I handle perspective projections in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, haskell, graphics, 3d, projection

I am currently writing a basic rendering demo using Haskell's OpenGL bindings. The problem is that it can barely handle 2000+ vertices. My pseudo-code amounts to this:

```
terrain = The set of points generated from [-1...1] x [-1...1] x [-1...1].
camera = Camera at position (xc, yc) with angles (ax, ay, az).
while running:
    input = anything that moves the camera's position or angles
    projected = []
    for point in terrain:
        projected.append(camera.perspectiveProjection(point))
    renderPoints(projected)
```

The problem (I believe) is that I am manually converting each of my three dimensional points into two dimensions and then using OpenGL to plot those points.

My question is: should I be feeding OpenGL three dimensional points and then using whatever projections OpenGL has baked in?

(I feel like I understand how perspective projections work - I'm just unsure if I should be doing this manually.)

EDIT:

The following is, for the most part, my code. I've left out sections that I feel are self-explanatory given only the function definition.

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
    initialDisplayMode $= [DoubleBuffered]
    _window <- createWindow "Hello, World"
    -- The camera position followed by pitch, yaw and roll.
    camera <- newIORef Camera [0,0,0] 0 0 0
    displayCallback $= display camera
    mainLoop

display :: IORef Camera -> DisplayCallback
display camIO = do
    camera <- get camIO
    clear [ColorBuffer, DepthBuffer]
    clear [ColorBuffer]
    renderPrimitive Points $ mapM_ vertex 
        $ map perspectiveProjection camera points
    swapBuffers
    postRedisplay Nothing
```

Comment: opengl is a rasterizer it does all the projection for you.  look at the [GLFW-b-demo](https://github.com/bsl/GLFW-b-demo) for a reasonably concise demo

Comment: "My question is: should I be feeding OpenGL three dimensional points and then using whatever projections OpenGL has baked in?"

Very likely, but it's hard for me to tell due to a lack of details. What are you trying to accomplish and how are you currently doing it? You gave some rough pseudo code, but telling us more about the exact API calls you're using would help. It's also unclear as to what you're trying to render.

Comment: @JasonDagit I've edited in an example of my code - hopefully that makes a bit more sense. My goal is to draw a bunch of vertices (`points`) in three dimensional space. Then, I want to listen for key presses and move a `Camera` object around within that space. The points should be rendered based on the camera's position and angle.

Comment: Just to make sure: did you roll out your own (CPU-based) projection algorithm?

Comment: Yes which is probably super slow.

Comment: What opengl version are you targeting? Based on the version there are multiple ways to handle the projection, you can use built in code to pass 3d points and let opengl handle the projection or you ca have a projection matrix that you pass to a vertex shader for rendering. The second case is the industry standard right now because it gives you more flexibility.

Comment: @Raxvan I would prefer to use the current standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you guessed correctly, rolling out your own projection algorithm can be very slow. Also, unless you're doing something extremely complicated, OpenGL(or more specifically GLU) has a set of functions that solves most of your problems.

The simplest way to do a traditional perspective projection is to have a camera with a position, look-to point and up vector. Personally, I find this simpler than defining the camera axis with rotation angles. Once you have this, you could have your display function like this:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GLU.Matrix

display :: IORef Camera -> DisplayCallback
display camIO = do
    camera <- get camIO
    perspective fov aspect zNear zFar
    lookAt (position camera) (lookAt camera) (upVector camera)
    -- call clear functions
    -- call renderPrimitive with the untransformed points.
```

The `lookAt` function changes the camera position and direction, give the camera attributes. The `perspective` is a function that takes information about the camera and window, and creates a proper perspective projection. If you find it to not give enough control about the projection, you could use `frustum` from `Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.CoordTrans` instead.

PS.: the correct way to do this would be to have a `setup` function, which setups the projection matrix, and have the display function change the modelview matrix, if necessary. The above code, however, should work.

PS2.: as pointed out in a comment, the way to implement this depends heavily on the OpenGL version, and I don't know which versions of OpenGL haskell supports. This implementation is based on OpenGL 2.1 and below.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I would prefer to target OpenGL 3+, though.

Comment: @sdasdadas OpenGL 2.1 is enabled as default in most systems, and you can use other versions if the driver allows it. If you really want to target them, you could create shaders and do all the transformations on them. A superficial look at the API tells me haskell doesn't support it (fully) though.

Comment: I see - well, then I will accept this answer as it is quite helpful. As an aside, I also found this to be useful (although I don't know which version of OpenGL it uses): http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Haskell-OpenGL-Mandelbrot/